# codeigniter, 404 not found error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a web site and I have installed CodeIgniter 2 Site under sub folder (`test`)

Users can access the site by using following link:

http://www.example.com/test/

When user is going to access (`test`) site using above link URL redirected to following link and following error will displayed.

http://www.example.com/test/login

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /test/login was not found on this server.

Then I add `index.php` to the above URL, login page displayed.

http://www.example.com/test/index.php/login

When I submit my username and password again URL redirected to, without logged on.

http://www.example.com/test/login

And again, not found.

`.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] =  '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO" ;
```

I have tried `$config['base_url'] = "http://www.example.com/test"` - still not working.

Comment: did you load url helper ? in autoload.php `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Comment: remove space between / / `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/test'`

Comment: Check all controllers and models file names and class names have first letter upper case

Comment: this site working in localhost but online not working

Comment: test this `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';`  Or   `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

Comment: @NithinKrishnanP not working

Answer (score 1):

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in .htaccess (place outside application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: nothing happen... .. my code worked properly on my localhost. but not in web server.

Comment: live url to check this out??

Comment: live url ; http://www.noritake.lk/themes/  please check, with index.php http://www.noritake.lk/themes/index.php/login , cant login , redirected to http://www.noritake.lk/themes/login

Comment: did you place `htaccess ` out side of folder??

Comment: htaccess in noritake.lk/themes folder

Comment: your problem is with htaccess file. So change that correctly. It will work out

Comment: is should be place **outside of application folder**

Comment: i have tried all htaccess files given here. i dont know what is the error.

Comment: htaccess files in noritake.lk/themes foloder, not in noritake.lk/themes/application, there is no htacceess file in noritake.lk/themes/application folder

Comment: use my `.htaccess` file .make sure you place out side application folder and file name is correct. There is no any other errors

Comment: where should i place htaccess file. please give me a folder path

Comment: so in themes folder, there should be **application** folder, then **index.php**, then **system** folder, then you should place **.htaccess**. got it??

Comment: yes! in themes folder, i have folders like application, system and files htaccess and index.php, is it correct?

Comment: htacess name should be `.(dot)htaccess`, that **DOT** is important in file name

Comment: and place this my htaccess code. and upload it back to server

Comment: file uploaded to noritake.lk/themes folder

Comment: done. $config['base_url'] =  '';$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: it cant be happen . your Ci version is 3.0??

Comment: system/core/CodeIgniter.php: says, define('CI_VERSION', '2.1.4');

Comment: I cant figged out whats error in your matter. in your form `<form role="form" action="http://www.noritake.lk/themes/login" method="post">`. set to same path `http://www.noritake.lk/themes/login`

Comment: please explain,, my login view;     <form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>login" method="post">

Comment: i think above form is correct. please explain there are any issue here with

Answer (score 0):

replace .htaccess with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```